# Check for undefined in one if condition with or

Tags: javascript

```
if(!parent[0] || parent[0].style.display !== 'none') {
    console.log('1');
}
```

I am trying to do this in one line, but it is failing in Firefox giving Type Error that parent[0] is undefined. But here I am trying to check and just do the if loop if it is. So my only solution to break it in two if's like this:

```
if(!parent[0]) {
    console.log('1');
    return;
}

if(parent[0].style.display !== 'none') {
    console.log('1');
}
```

How can I make it in one line? Why the first code fails and says that parent[0] is undefined, how can I prevent that and just do the console log which is inside.

Comment: you probably need `&&` instead of `||` in your condition

Comment: `if(parent[0] && parent[0].style.display !== 'none') `

Comment: *do the if loop...* `if` is not a loop. Its a conditional statement. Also can you share the actual error?

Comment: you haven't shown us what `parent[0]` is, because if it's not there -you will get a type error in any other browser. Every time and any time the `parent` reference is empty eg has no members. Meaning your error is coming from the OR statement trying to access `style` display property of a member that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
if(parent[0] && parent[0].style.display !== 'none') {
    console.log('1');
}
```

Using `someVariable && condition` means that `someVariable` is defined and condition is met.

In my opinion the most readable code is:

```
function doSomething() {
  // if condition is not met we quit the function
  if(parent[0] === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  // parent[0] is defined we proceed
  // Perhaps other conditions that should quit the function
  if(parent[0].style.display === 'none') {
    return false;
  }
  // parent[0] is defined we proceed and all checks are done
  // All your logic here
}
```

Comment: but I also want it to fire, if it is undefined. and if display is 'none'

Comment: If element is `undefined`, it means element does not exist and has no `style`.

Comment: if you want to check if element is undefined just do `if(element === undefined) { /* your code */ }`

Comment: @Vikast See my updated answer and how you could implement your code to make it more readable.

Comment: I was thinking that this can be achieved in one line, but yes, this is what I was pointing also, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic to `&&`.

```
if(parent[0] && parent[0].style.display !== 'none') {
    console.log('1');
}
```

Comment: `parent[0]` not `!parent[0]`

Comment: Right, thanks.  This is why we don't copy/paste code :)

Comment: what if the zero index member of `parent` doesn't have a `style` property?

Answer (score 0):

so I suggest you try:

```
"style" in parent[0] ? parent[0].style.display == "none" ? console.log(1) : 0 : 0;
```

Beware that if the `display` property is not set by javascript action, it will not reflect the state of the requested property. e.g.: you'll get an empty string instead.